# How to output dictionary of forms in django template

Tags: python, django, forms, list, dictionary

I am saving a list of forms as a variable in the view that I am sending to the template.

When I iterate the list of forms in the template, it gives me the error

> AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'get'

I've tried originally to save the forms in a dictionary, but got the same error.  I can iterate through a queryset that I'm passing to the template, but the list, or dictionary, of forms cannot seem to be iterated.

Is there any solution for this?

Here's my relevant code:

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from apps.account.models import UserProfile

class StaffUserTypeForm(forms.Form):
    user_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=UserProfile.STAFF_CHOICES)
```

account/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    DEFAULT = 0
    ADMIN = 1
    MANAGER = 2
    COORDINATOR = 3
    REALTOR = 4
    TEAM_CAPTAIN = 5
    PROPERTY_OWNER = 6
    PRELOAD = 7
    BILLING = 8
    COORDINATOR_PRELOAD = 9

    STAFF_CHOICES = (
        (ADMIN, 'Admin'),
        (MANAGER, 'Manager'),
        (COORDINATOR, 'Coordinator'),
        (COORDINATOR_PRELOAD, 'Coordinator +Preload'),
        (PRELOAD, 'Preloader'),
        (BILLING, 'Billing'),
    )
    ...
```

views.py

```
from forms import *
    ...
    staff = Staff.objects.all()
    roles = []
    for member in staff:
        form = StaffUserTypeForm(initial=member.user.userprofile.user_type)
        roles.append(form)
    context.update({'staff':staff,'roles':roles})
    ...
```

template (This is where it breaks)

```
{% for role in roles %}
{{role}}
{% endfor %}
```

But this works fine:

```
{% for member in staff %}
{{member.user.first_name}}
{% endfor %}
```

### Update

That particular error is because I didn't specify user_type in `initial` for the form.

Should be:

```
form = StaffUserTypeForm(initial={'user_type':member.user.userprofile.user_type})
```

However, I still have the problem of spitting out the form for each staffmember, because I can't reference a variable as a dictionary key within the template:

if:

```
roles = {}
for member in staff:
  roles[member] = StaffUserTypeForm(initial={'user_type':member.user.userprofile.user_type})
```

I can't get the form for the specific staffmember:

```
{% for member in staff %}
{{roles.member}}
{% endfor %}
```

Does not work, and does not throw an error.  It just looks, I think, for roles['member'] which doesn't exist.

Comment: You should use a [model formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets). Also, you should post the full stacktraces when you have an exception.

Comment: Are you sure that this for with role in roles making error ?

Comment: Error was that I didn't send a dictionary as the initial value in the form.  However, still can't reference the form in the for loop.  I believe it's a template problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `roles` dictionary contains both the members (as keys) and forms (as values), why do you need to iterate through `staff` at all? Just iterate through `roles`.

```
{% for member, form in roles.items %}
    {{ member }} : {{ form }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Works like a charm.  I was thinking I had to make a template filter to pass the variable as a key: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3371.  You've saved me some time!  Thanks.